# android keyboard influence on the UI

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard

In my android application I have edittext , after focusing on it (touching for input the text) the keyboard is opening and compressing my listView's backgorund. how to fix this?  and where I can read more information about keyboard influence on UI? Thanks

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the behavior of the keyboard in the `Manifest.xml` file.

I suggest you to read the documentation about [configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) and [windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

You may want to use the `adjustPan` option for your compressing issue.

> **adjustPan** : The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. [...]

Comment: I'm trying right now :), thanks for response to question , if anything I'll add a comment :)

Comment: Nothing helped , I tried all ways , but it continue to compress my listView's background, I tried to put my listview in some Layout , and give the same background to this layout , but it didn't work too